# I get a failure for my code but I don´t know the reason

Tags: java, return, boolean, illegalargumentexception

```
/**
 * Checks whether a given value is in a given range defined by its lowest and highest possible value
 * Both of the borders of the range (lowestPossible, highestPossible) are considered to be inside of the range
 * An IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the highestPossible value is less than the lowestPossible value
 * @param lowestPossible The lowest possible value of the range
 * @param highestPossible The highest possible value of the range
 * @param guess The value that has been guessed
 * @return <code>true</code> if the guess is withing the given range; <code>false</code> otherwise
 */
public static boolean isWithinBorders(int lowestPossible, int highestPossible, int guess) {
   // return false; // TODO: IMPLEMENT ME (AND DELETE THIS COMMENT AFTERWARDS!!!)
```

When I run the test, I get zero errors, but I also get one failure. What could be the reaseon for the failure? I don´t get any error informations in my console or next to my code on the left side shown :(

My Code:

```
    if (guess > lowestPossible & guess < highestPossible) { //is value guess between highest & lowest number?
        //if (lowestPossible < highestPossible && highestPossible > lowestPossible) {  //
        return true;
            
    }else if(highestPossible < lowestPossible) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("lowestPossible can´t be higher then highestPossible");
            
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: By failure do you mean illegal argument exception?

Comment: If you don't get any output, how do you know there is a failure? --- *"When I run the test"* What test?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: Please notice that the fact that your problem was solved in no way justifies vandalizing your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The arguments `highest` and `lowest` should be validated first
2. There is a requirement that `lowest` and `highest` are within the range `[lowest, highest]`, while existing code excludes these values `(lowest, highest)`
3. `&` is a bitwise operator, `&&` should be used as logical AND operator
4. The last `return` is redundant

Thus, the correct code may look like:

```java
public static boolean isWithinBorders(int lowest, int highest, int guess) {
    if (highest < lowest) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lowest must be less than highest");
    }
    return lowest <= guess && guess <= highest;
}
```